# A better name for the chat room

Tags: discussion, status-completed

The current name for the chat room is simply "Biology". I think we can do better than that. Suggest a new, descriptive and more imaginative name for the chat room. One name per answer, please.

Comment: How about: "the chat room"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

My suggestion:

***The Biosphere***

Answer (score 10):

How about calling the chat room

> **The Synapse**

[*where info is transmitted*]

Comment: Inhibitory or excitatory?? :D

Answer (score 7):

How about calling the chat room

> **Cross Talk**

[*Where channels interact, for the better or worse :)*]

Comment: I don't know, people could confuse it with [stats.se]...

Answer (score 1):

Admittedly, this is very similar to *WYSIWYG*'s suggestion, but what about:

> **The Biome**

Answer (score 1):

In reference to Darwin's famous quote, what about:

> **The Entangled Bank**

or

> **Darwin's Entangled Bank**

As reference, this is from the last paragraph of *The Origin of Species*:

> It is interesting to contemplate an entangled bank, clothed with many plants of many kinds, with birds singing on the bushes, with various insects flitting about, and with worms crawling through the damp earth, and to reflect that these elaborately constructed forms, so different from each other, and dependent on each other in so complex a manner, have all been produced by laws acting around us.

which could be restated as:

> It is interesting to contemplate an **entangled bank**, clothed with many **users** of many kinds, with **moderators** singing on the bushes, with **random users** flitting about, and with **trolls** crawling through the damp earth, and to reflect that these elaborately constructed **user types**, so different from each other, and dependent on each other in so complex a manner, have all been produced by the guidelines and metaposts acting at **BiologySE**.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the title if the chatroom is just fine. It also teals you, that the chatroom is about Biology.

Answer (score 0):

How about **Genesis** :P

[Just to make 30 characters :D]

Answer (score -1):

Biodome[image]

Comment: Source of picture?

Answer (score -2):

> The Dawn Chorus

[From birds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dawn_chorus_(birds)).

Answer (score -4):

***Lab 19***

Essentially, lab because that's where most of us spend our lives in, and 19 is the building number of Cavendish labs in Cambridge, where Watson and Crick were based out of.

Answer (score -4):

How about

> The DNA Lounge

?

Answer (score -4):

Suggestion:
Endless Forms Most Beautiful

Comment: I guess no one appreciates Darwin…

Comment: @canadianer What does Darwin have to do with it?

Comment: @FaheemMitha He wrote it…

Comment: @canadianer Wrote what?

Comment: @FaheemMitha The book that this answer quotes